# lambda code to capitalize column not working

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, lambda

When I execute the `Python 3.4.4` code below to capitalize values under the ident column,  I get no errors but my output is not capitalized. Need help figuring out the problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#Create a dataframe

data = {'ident': ['Jack', 'Mary', 'Teresa', 'James', 'Anna'], 
        'year': [2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2007], 
        'reports': [67, 5, 36, 9, 14],
        'scope': [17, 102, 57, 49, 77]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['Bahia', 'Pico', 'Santa Fe', 'Maine', 
'Zuma'])
#Create a capitalizer function
capitalize = lambda x: x.upper()

#Create a capitalizing function over the column 'ident'

df['ident'].apply(capitalize)
print (df)
```

Comment: By the way.  This doesn't answer your question.  That's answered below.  However, you don't need a separate `lambda`.  You could do, `df['ident'].apply(str.upper)`.  You failed to reassign the column.  See answers below.

Comment: Think Python should have one canonical Q&A that says - **Please assign back the results**.

Comment: @Divakar we have been seeing so many question from it ...when they do replace , apply, append ...

Answer (score 3):

Changes to the data frame are not directly saved back. Replace

```
df['ident'].apply(capitalize)
```

with

```
df['ident'] = df['ident'].apply(capitalize)
```

and it will work.

So the complete code looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#Create a dataframe

data = {'ident': ['Jack', 'Mary', 'Teresa', 'James', 'Anna'],
        'year': [2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2007],
        'reports': [67, 5, 36, 9, 14],
        'scope': [17, 102, 57, 49, 77]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['Bahia', 'Pico', 'Santa Fe', 'Maine','Zuma'])
#Create a capitalizer function
capitalize = lambda x: x.upper()

#Create a capitalizing function over the column 'ident'

df['ident'] = df['ident'].apply(capitalize)
print (df)
```

Or do it even nicer (imho) `df.ident=df.ident.str.upper()`

Comment: You are changing the whole dataframe into series ident

Comment: See Edit: I forgot to address ident before. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

```
df.ident=df.ident.str.upper()
df
Out[1101]: 
           ident  reports  scope  year
Bahia       JACK       67     17  2001
Pico        MARY        5    102  2002
Santa Fe  TERESA       36     57  2003
Maine      JAMES        9     49  2004
Zuma        ANNA       14     77  2007
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the result back to df['ident']

```
df['ident'] = df['ident'].apply(capitalize)
```

Though I would simply use

```
df['ident'] = df['ident'].str.upper()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use lambda to uppercase specific columns, you can use this code:

```
 df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.upper() if x.name in ['column1'] else x)
```

or use this code for multiple specific columns:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.upper() if x.name in ['column1','column2','column3'] else x)
```